# Node.js browserify slow: isn't there a way to cache big libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm creating a file that requires huge libraries such as jquery and three.js using browserify. The compiling process takes several seconds, probably because it's recompiling all the libs for each minor change I make. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: How else will I be able to see that minor change on the resulting app?

Comment: @mihai http://o7.no/14GeQk8 program > compile on vim by pressing R > result appears on chrome > repeat. This was supposed to be instant, not 5~10s long.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried using the `--insert-globals`, `--ig`, or `--fast` flags? (they're all the same thing)

The reason it's slow may be that it's scanning all of jquery and d3 for `__dirname`, `__filename`, `process`, and `global` references.

EDIT:

I just remembered:  Browserify will take any pre-existing require functions and fall back to using that. [more info here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles)

This means you could build a bundle for your static libs, and then only rebuild the bundle for your app code on change.

This coupled with my pre-edit answer should make it a lot faster.

Comment: That's what I did (bundle for static libs), it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few options that can help:

`--noparse=FILE` is a must for things like jQuery and three.js that are huge but don't use `require` at all.

`--detect-globals` Set to false if your module doesn't use any node.js globals. Directs browserify not to parse a file looking for `process`, `global`, `__filename`, and `__dirname`.

`--insert-globals` Set to true if your module *does* use node.js globals. This will define those globals without parsing the module and checking to see if they're used.

I was able to speed up my build by `external`izing ThreeJS, using `noparse` with it, and setting it not to create a source map for it.

Use https://github.com/substack/watchify while developing.

Comment: Oh, very cool, thanks. Could you just exemplify a full command so I can be sure not to miss it? For example, just add --noparse=jquery and then every require for files called jquery are unparsed?

Comment: I'm using browserify-middleware, so I don't know exactly what the command line invocation would look like. Here's what I'm doing: https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/5747010

Comment: @Viclib hey, did you ever find the example of using `--noparse` ?

Comment: I retired from Node.js so I don't remember. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

If you use grunt, you can use my grunt task : https://github.com/amiorin/grunt-watchify

It caches the dependencies and watches the filesystem. Because of this the build is very fast. You can use it with grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-connect or alone. You can find a Gruntfile.js example in the github repository.

If you don't use grunt, you can use the original watchify from @substack : https://github.com/substack/watchify

Answer (score 5):

Using [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) is practically a must, as it actually caches your deps between reloads.

My builds dropped from 3-8s to under 1s. (The >3s builds were still using `ignoreGlobals`, `detectGlobals=false`, and even `noParse`ing jQuery).

Here's how I use it with gulp and coffeescript:

```
gutil = require("gulp-util")
source = require("vinyl-source-stream")
watchify = require("watchify")
browserify = require("browserify")
coffeeify = require("coffeeify")

gulp.task "watchify", ->
  args = watchify.args
  args.extensions = ['.coffee']
  bundler = watchify(browserify("./coffee/app.coffee", args), args)
  bundler.transform(coffeeify)

  rebundle = ->
    gutil.log gutil.colors.green 'rebundling...'
    bundler.bundle()
      # log errors if they happen
      .on "error", gutil.log.bind(gutil, "Browserify Error")
      # I'm not really sure what this line is all about?
      .pipe source("app.js")
      .pipe gulp.dest("js")
      .pipe livereload()
    gutil.log gutil.colors.green 'rebundled.'

  bundler.on "update", rebundle
  rebundle()

gulp.task "default", ["watchify", "serve"]
```

EDIT: here's a JS translation:

```
var gutil = require("gulp-util")
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream")
var watchify = require("watchify")
var browserify = require("browserify")
var coffeeify = require("coffeeify")

gulp.task("watchify", function() {
  var args = watchify.args
  args.extensions = ['.coffee']
  var bundler = watchify(browserify("./coffee/app.coffee", args), args)
  bundler.transform(coffeeify)

  function rebundle() {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('rebundling...'))
    bundler.bundle()
      // log errors if they happen
      .on("error", gutil.log.bind(gutil, "Browserify Error"))
      // I'm not really sure what this line is all about?
      .pipe(source("app.js"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("js"))
      .pipe(livereload())
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('rebundled.'))
  }

  bundler.on("update", rebundle)
  rebundle()
})

gulp.task("default", ["watchify", "serve"])
```

Comment: this works the first time.
but when i make any changes to the coffee script, it goes back to parse the cached js file and throws the following error

`ParseError: reserved word "var"`

Comment: Hmm. I don't know what to tell you; the above script has been working for me for a while now, including after the first time. Perhaps you are attempting to run the "coffee" transform on javascript files?

Comment: Can you please provide an answer in JavaScript rather than CoffeeScript, as the question has the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

You can also give it a try to [persistify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/persistify) which can be used as a drop in replacement for watchify from the command line and from code.

Original answer below

=======

I'm currently using `bundly`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundly

**FULL DISCLOUSURE**: I wrote it

But the main difference of this wrapper is that it provides incremental building. It persists the `browserify` cache between runs and only parse the files that have changed without the need for the watch mode.

Currently the module does a bit more than only adding the cache, but I'm thinking that the logic that handles the incremental build part could be moved to a plugin, that way it can be used with browserify directly.

Check a demo here: https://github.com/royriojas/bundly-usage-demo

Comment: I've just setup persistify, and it's exactly what I've always wanted.  Reduced my initial startup time immensely.  From 15 seconds to 2 seconds.  It was very easy to replace browserify and watchify in my gulp build. Worked the first time.  I've tested a few cases and everything works as expected.  So refreshing!   THANKS ROY!!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this to solve the problem of slow builds with browserify and commonjs-everywhere.  If you run it in "watch" mode then it will automatically watch your input files and incrementally rebuild just any files that changed.  Basically instantaneous and will never get slower as your project grows.

https://github.com/krisnye/browser-build